# Change destination of link once active

Tags: javascript, html, css

Not sure what I'm looking for but I was wondering if there's a way to change the name of a link when it's made active as well as it's destination. A toggle of sorts.

Below is a mock-up.

[image]

There will only be one button on show.

Comment: What do mean by active ?

Comment: why don't you just change the name in source code for page about so link have blog in name and vice versa?

Comment: @ChandraSekharWalajapet if i'm on the about page the blog link is displayed, when i'm on the blog page the about link replaces the blog link

Answer (score 2):

based on url you can change your link text and href.

```
var a = document.getElementById('linkId');
if(location.href == abouturl){
 a.href = blogurl;
 a.innerHTML = 'BLOG'
}
else{
   a.href = abouturl;
   a.innerHTML= 'ABOUT';
}
```

Comment: The above solution is not 100% fool proof until unless you either convert to lower or upper case the location.href value, it's human entry and I suspect

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery.

```
var linkObj = $("#linkId");
if(location.href == aboutUrl){
  linkObj.attr("href", blogurl).html("BLOG");
}
else{
  linkObj.attr("href", abouturl).html("ABOUT");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this with CSS

```
.collection-506d943d84aead5098d63cc2 
#main-navigation 
.blog-collection {
  display:none;
}

.collection-506daf5a84aead5098d68b94 
#main-navigation 
.page-collection {
  display: none;
}
```